# PHP several ways to reset a variable

Tags: php, string, variables, null, unset

I know a few methods to reset a variable in PHP.

Problem is that I don't know exactly what is the difference between
them and who is faster so here I'm asking...

What is the difference between :

```
<?php

$resetME = null;
//VS    
unset($resetME);
//VS
$resetME = 0;

?>
```

and...

I would be happy to know if there is other tricks to completely remove a variable from memory.

Moreover, I would LOVE to know if there is any reason to reset a variable on the end of the page since server reset them anyways when page fully loaded...

Just to clarify more...

```
<?php

$a = 1;
echo $a;

//is there any reason to unset $a on the end of the page ?
unset($a);

?>
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$resetME = null; -- wouldn't erase var from memory

unset($resetME); -- erase var from memory

$resetME = 0; -- wouldn't erase var from memory

To completely remove a variable from memory you need to use unset. 
All other ways just change variable value

But if variable wouldn't exists, you'll receive error in this unset($resetME);

Better way to use $resetME = null;

After script ends, PHP will clean memory.

Comment: Thanks ! One quick question... Is there any reason to unset a variable at the end of the page (last line) to free some memory or server is reset them anyways ?

Comment: Server reset all vars after script complete. In my opinion, you don't need to unset variables, PHP will do this for you.